# Basic Query Regarding Work and Energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

Assertion:Energy changes the kinetic only, and changes in potential require an intermediate change in kinetic.

Reasoning:
eg:when I throw a ball upward I do work/transfer energy,At the topmost point, there's a changed potential which is an effect of changing its position through its ke.

eg:when I lift a weight at constant ke,Im transferring energy to increase the kinetic as I'm doing work against gravity , I can't change the potential without changing the kinetic.

I did some research but the only answer I could find is an input of energy can increase both kinetic and potential but I don't see how it changes the potential without changing the kinetic.

this seems to make sense for a lot of situations and i need to realize where im going wrong with this
My question is: Is this valid and if it is does it hold for all fields in physics? Can energy only change the kinetic and require an intermediate change in kinetic to alter the potential?

Comment: "Despite Energy being an intuitive topic..." Your question underlines the hubris of this assertion...

Comment: @hft it shows how I'm aware it might not make a lot of sense , and I'm just here to know why not.

Comment: The 3rd paragraph is inconsistent. Is the KE constant or is it increasing?

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm increasing kinetic to maintain a constant kinetic

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this valid and if it is does it hold for all fields in physics? Can energy only change the kinetic and require an intermediate change in kinetic to alter the potential?

No, this is not correct in any field of physics that I am aware of. Even in basic Newtonian mechanics if a weight is lifted upwards at constant velocity then its potential energy is increasing because it is moving upwards while its kinetic energy is constant because the velocity is constant.

Comment: even here i see the energy required to keep the weight at constant velocity is requiring some energy which changes the kinetic and not the potential, the potential is later changed due to the change in kinetic[according to my observation]

Comment: There is simply no way around it nor any ambiguity. Constant speed means constant KE. Constant KE means no change in KE.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't see how it changes the potential without changing the kinetic.

Obviously we can't change position without motion and motion gives us kinetic energy. But we can change PE *without a change in KE*.

Consider lifting an object at rest on the ground and raising it to bring it at rest a height $h$ above the ground. Since the object begins and ends at rest $\Delta KE=0$ whereas $\Delta PE=mgh$. Or consider raising the object at constant velocity from point A to point B where the vertical distance between the two points is $h$. The object possesses KE but there is *no change in KE*, and we still have $\Delta PE=mgh$.

In short, changes in PE depend only on changes in position and not the manner in which the change in position occurs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: alright that makes sense , would saying kinetic is required to alter the potential energy make sense?

Comment: A change in kinetic energy is not required to alter potential energy. But motion is required to to alter potential energy

Answer (score 1):

> For instance, when I throw a ball upward I do work/transfer energy,
> At the topmost point, there's a changed potential which is an effect of changing its position through its ke.

It is possible only when we are concerning ourselves to conservative fields such as those of gravitation or coulombic. It also requires that the only force acting on body is of convervative field.

> I did some research but the only answer I could find is an input of energy can be both kinetic and potential but I don't see how it changes the potential without changing the kinetic.

Potential is something which only depends on relative position. We can change it without altering the kinetic energy, all we need is an external force.

e.g. Imagine a drop moving at terminal velocity, because of external air resistance. Its kinetic energy is constant, but its potential energy is changing at each interval of time.

Comment: even here i see the external air resistance transferring some energy which alters the kinetic energy , i don't see the potential energy changing without altering the kinetic. even here change in potential is due to a change in kinetic? there's got to be something wrong with the way I'm viewing this , i just want to know the right way.

Comment: To @micropasta :- Apply Newton's 2nd law. $\sum_{i=1}^{n}F_{i}=0$, hence the net work done is zero. As a consequence, change in kinetic energy is zero.